# как добавить в список определенное кол-во вещей

Tags: c#

как добавить в список определенное кол-во вещей...
для примера

```
List<Apple> apple = new List<Apple>(); // создаю список яблок
apple.Add(new Apple());// добавил одно яблоко
```

если мне нужно добавить 1000 яблок я же не буду писать apple.Add .. 1000раз) 
и мне нужно добавлять именно яблоки а не числа
// В гугле не нашел ничего путного, может плохо искал(

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { apple.Add(new Apple()); }`

Comment: @Igor Спасибо большое )

Comment: галочка слева от ответа - щёлк :) Успехов!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант в одну строку:

```
List<Apple> apple = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(x => new Apple()).ToList();
```

---

либо как указал  комментарии @Igor, можно через цикл `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { 
    apple.Add(new Apple()); 
}
```